# How might one stop pruning when started in monerod?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, monerod-commands

How do I gracefully stop blockchain pruning done by `monerod`?
I have started `monerod` to update the blockchain and when it finished syncing it I decided to try to save some disk space as the database grew to a lot.

I started pruning by running the prune-blockchain command inside of monerod. Sadly, I later learned that [such way of pruning does not do any good for the disk space usage](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11356/how-to-enable-pruning-in-the-command-line-of-the-monero-blockchain-in-version-v0). Now I want to gracefully stop this process in order to not corrupt the existing database.

I have tried from a new shell to do

```
monerod exit
```

this indicates that the signal for termination is sent but the deamon keeps running. The shell where monerod is running does not react to any input.

How might I stop pruning gracefully when it was started by prune_blockchain from `monerod` cli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One does not. Pruning is a long one shot operation.

If your database is too large, pruning in place will not actually decrease the file size. You will need to resync from scratch with --prune-blockchain for this, which neatly moots your question in the first place :)

Comment: I found this question while looking for how long one can expect pruning to take. I have not found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you run the newest version on a Linux 64-bit environment as I do. Also assuming that your paths relative to `~` are the same as mine.

Open a new tab in your bash terminal and run:

`~/monero-x86_64-linux-gnu-v0.17.1.9/monerod exit`

It works on my PC, yielding:

> 2021-02-08 14:45:33.770    I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.1.9-release)
>
> Stop signal sent

In order to monitor the latest of your `monerod` open a separate tab in your Bash terminal and run:

`tail -f ~/.bitmonero/bitmonero.log`

P.S. It stops my client that was started by ~/monero-x86_64-linux-gnu-v0.17.1.9/monerod --detach`. I've not done any pruning yet.

Comment: Thank for your input, I have tried to stop the deamon this way but it did not work